# Silently change the class? is it possible in Ruby

Tags: ruby, class

I develop classes for a technical drawing solution. I have to work with geometrical primitives. Ex:

```
# all specifications are left, bottom and width, height
class Circle
                      #  +--- this is for my later question
                      #  v 
   def initialize(x,y,w,h=w) # left, bottom and w=x+2*radius
      ...
   end
end
# the Ellipse needs 4 specifications (no rotation here)
class Ellipse
   def initialize(x,y,w,h) # left, bottom and w=2*a, h=2*b
      ...
   end
end
```

If somebody would use something like

```
primitive=Cricle.new(10,10,20,30) # note different width and height
```

would it be possible to return a `Ellipse` instead (a bit like:*'be liberal in what you accept ...'* Jon Postel's robustness principle)?

I think that just `include Ellipse` should do the trick, since Circle and Ellibse are more or less equal, I didnt try that, but would that change `class.name`, and what would happen (within Ruby), if I do that?

Comment: I do not think that this makes sense. Because these differ only by those dimensions, I do not believe there is a need for another class. A circle is an ellipse.

Comment: @Ross: yes, it is, calculating the area of a circle thinking of it as a ellipse with a=b, is expensive, and using "if" breaks OO. I think there is a reason why even in SVG  there is a <circle> and a <ellipse> tag

Comment: OK, then inheritance is the answer! (like Jeffrey's answer below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def Circle.new(x,y,w,h)
  if w != h
    Ellipse.new x,y,w,h
  else
    super
  end
end
```

Comment: This is an realy short answer, looks correct for me, so I have to explain it my self: I override the 'new' operator of class Circle, returning ether an instance of Circle or an instance of Ellipse?

Comment: Em.. You should get more info about how Class.new works. Read the book "The Ruby programming language" by David Flanagan and Yukihiro Matsumoto (the language creator).

Comment: As of your question: yes, looks so. But seriously, read the book. =)

P.S. Never do the same tricks in real code ;)

Comment: :-D - I should get more information how ruby works! comming from C++ and PHP, it often causes knots in my brain, I will read it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can (within the `Circle` class just add the following):

```
def self.new(x, y, w, h)
  return Ellipse.new(x, y, w, h) if w != h
  super
end
```

The point is that, yes, just like you said this is very bad practice. In this very case you can organize things a little bit better and you generally should never end up writing such an hack. Here's an example:

```
class Ellipse
    def initialize(x, y, w, h = w)
        # (x, y) is the origin point
        # w = width, h = height
        # ...
    end
end

class Circle < Ellipse
    def initialize(x, y, d)
        # (x, y) is the origin point
        # d = diameter
        # ...
        super x, y, d, d
    end
end
```

In fact a Circle is a special case of an Ellipse. And by doing the above you are making it clear by specializing the constructor of `Ellipse` within the `Circle#initialize` method.

Comment: sry, my question was for understanding Ruby, not OO. In my case all methods of 'Circle' and 'Ellipse' are different, subclassing this, is an acadmic question, and should not (IMHo) be a point of this task. But thanks(!) for your example. It makes my question clearer: what if I get an ellipse with h=w, I should return a 'Circle' to keep calculations low. In this case this bad 'hack' starts to make sense :-) - "you need to know the rules, to break them correct" lama.